# ModelService.Filtered does not return data on mobile device

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, maximo-anywhere, mobilefirst-studio

I am attempting to use the ModelService.filtered function to check for existing records in the Maximo. In this use case, I request data using a filter, and if it returns results I perform additional actions.

The problem that I am having is that the code works as expected in the browser, but does not work as expected on device. For the same condition the browser returns records, and the mobile device does not.

This function had previously worked for this use case in Maximo Anywhere 7.5.1.2, but appears to have been altered for 7.6.1, and I cannot achieve the same results from the new code.

Here is my code:

```
    var selectedResource = eventContext.getResource().getCurrentRecord();
    var currentUser = UserManager.getCurrentUser();
    var myTask = selectedResource.get('wonum');
    var siteid = selectedResource.get('siteid');
    var isremoved = false;
    var filter ={'thtaskwo':myTask,'thsiteid':siteid,'thhelper':currentUser,'isremoved':isremoved};
    ModelService.filtered('sftaskhelperresource', null, filter, null, true, null, null, null, false).then(function(result){
                    if(result.count()>0){
                //some additional code here
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: have you checked the parameters for the function? One of them is about forceServerPreferred and one forceLocalPreferred. http://maximodev.blogspot.nl/p/anywhere-reference-modelservice.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and here is my solution;

You can actually debug from the application itself.

Go to `Settings > Advance Settings > Logging`. Click the `More` menu button on the top-right and click `Enable Logging` (Error, Info, and Debug).

Run the filter step from the app until the part where it fails to display the filter result. Go back to logging as per above and you can see the info/error;

[image: Logging Data]

As you can see, it said attribute "attributename" is not indexed in "resource" JSONStore. You need to put index="true" in resource definition for the attribute that you want to filter and it will work.

Thank you